# Solidity cannot handle my huge token ids inside my function

Tags: solidity, metamask

I am trying to parse token ids into my solidity function to allow the user to swap his token with another user once authed and everything.

My issue is that when I try to handle the big token id that the client comes to the site with, its too large and Metamask just shows something like this:
[image: Metamask popup showing contract error]

The price in Gas for sending just 1 token ID is saying $304 but it won't go through.

My solidity function to grab the token ids inputted:

```
function sendETHER(address payable to) public payable {
    (bool sent,) = to.call{value: msg.value}("");
    require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");
}

function swapBatch(IERC1155 contractAddy, address from, address to, uint256[] calldata nftIDs, uint256[] calldata nftValues, bytes calldata data, address payable tothem) public payable {
    contractAddy.safeBatchTransferFrom(from, to, nftIDs, nftValues, data);
    sendETHER(tothem);
}
```

The token id i am trying to parse is:
37505722872311826684420363920427329579320092872507435601572703609282712761931
Which shows it's less than the 2^256 that can hold inside uint256:
115792090000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

So i'm not too sure as to why it's not letting my contract go through.

I am approved and allowed to send but it won't go through...

Answer (score 0):

It might be not related to a long token id. Such a message from Metamask means that the transaction will fail. You should test this on a local machine first to understand where the issue lies.

If you need mainnet state, you can [fork mainnet on your local machine](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/guides/forking-other-networks) and execute that transaction to debug why it is failing.